# Copy vector to vector in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I have to acomplish an elementary copy of one vector to another when to points
of the one vector lay in a contour.
Here are the two vectors and the code:

```
vector<Vec4i> lines,sheaf[10][200];

for (size_t j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec4i l = lines[i];
        if ((pointPolygonTest(contours[j], Point2f(l[0], l[1]), false) >= 0) && (pointPolygonTest(contours[j], Point2f(l[2], l[3]), false) >= 0))
        {
            sheaf[j][n] = lines[i];
            n++;
        }
    }
```

I got this massage for this line `sheaf[j][n] = lines[i];`

> Error  3   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'cv::Vec' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    C:\Users\Eltimir\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenCV_2_4_10\vanishingPoints\Source.cpp 88  1   vanishingPoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sheaf[10][200] declares a bidimensional array of vector. Your declarations should be:

```
vector<Vec4i> lines;
Vec4i sheaf[10][200];
```